# integrate existing PHP session with MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have a site and want to integrate a Wiki into it.

I know I can change my code to register and/or set wiki cookies when the user login but this will slow the system down especially since not every user will visit the wiki.

is there a way to make the wiki check if a PHP Session exists and automatically show the logged in users from the main site also logged in on the wiki?

I tried looking into SessionManager and AuthManager but the documentary is too complicated for me since it's my first time working with MediaWiki. if anyone can point me to the right part of the docs for me it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: "I know I can change my code to register and/or set wiki cookies when the user login but this will slow the system down especially since not every user will visit the wiki." sending a cookie takes almost no time. Is there another part to that approach that would add significant time/overhead?

Comment: because after I implement this, whenever a user logs in the code has to sign him up in the wiki and most users won't visit the wiki ever. it sounds more efficient and data saving if only the users who will visit the wiki will be registered and then logged in to the wiki

Comment: It's also probably going to be relevant knowing what authernicaton method you are using for the main site. If it's a central authentication process, like a SAML IdP or an LDAP server, there are probably existing plugins for mediawiki to handle already-authenticated users from other services. Otherwise, you will probably need to code your own solution for informing mediawiki that the user is already authenticated (and as I understand it, you aren't doing too well with complicated solutions).

Comment: I'm using my own php code to do the authernicaton. it's very basic.
I just need to be pointed in the right direction to start from. how will SessionManager call my code if no cookies were available? or if this even possible with this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's what session providers are for. Something like this might work:

```
MySessionProvider extends ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie {
    public function provideSessionInfo( WebRequest $request ) {
        $user = getUserFromCustomCookies();
        if ( $user ) {
            return new SessionInfo( SessionInfo::MAX_PRIORITY, [
                'provider' => $this,
                'id' => md5( $user->getName() ),
                'userInfo' => UserInfo::newFromUser($user, true),
                'persisted' => false,
             ] );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Do NOT set the `sessionCookie*` params.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did a lot of reading and this or using `Auth_remoteuser` seems to be the best way. But in both cases the data I need to authenticate the user must be saved in cookies, my project uses PHP Sessions to save this data and calling `session_start()` in my code stops the wiki from starting session. is there a way around this?

Comment: You could try setting `$wgPHPSessionHandling = 'disable'` which completely detaches MediaWiki session handling from PHP sessions. It's largely untested though.

Comment: Alternatively, just save and restore the previous session.